# How to unrar (using UI)

Tags: software-installation, rar

How can I unrar files? And please I want a program with UI... WinRAR would be the best (I have a license, I know, I'm like a unicorn). Ubuntu is so confusing and not user friendly at all imho. I just want a program (again, WinRAR would be nice) that gives me a right click menu to extract, a UI to open the files... basically a windows like solution. And please tell me how to install it - noobfriendly please.

Comment: "UI" means "User Interface", and could cover anything from a morse code key connected to the serial port, to a "glass keypunch", to a touchscreen, to a Graphical User Interface like X windows.

Comment: Try [PeaZip](https://peazip.github.io/peazip-linux.html) GUI program. It has portable build without installation. It's [Open Source](https://github.com/peazip/PeaZip)

Answer (score 2):

Install `unrar` using `sudo apt-get install unrar` and "Archive Manager" can unrar the file for you

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Unrar is from WInRAR and therefore not free, right? How can I register it with my license?

Comment: @J.DoeII you don't. non-free means there are copyrights, it doesn't mean that it costs money

Comment: And with this little thing I can extract RAR, including RAR5, ZIP and all the other standards?

Comment: @J.DoeII you will have to install 7zip to extract 7z files but yes, just right click and select extract here.

Comment: @J.DoeII here is all things about the `file-roller` and supported extensions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/File%20Roller

Answer (score 1):

well if you want to extract a RAR file you can do it the same way you can in windows with 7zip :)

$sudo apt-get install 7zip
if the code does not work then try
downloading a debian file from the main page or using the software center happy extracting :)

Comment: Too bad there is no real WinRAR version for Ubuntu 7zip is quite ugly. Sorry. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please install unzip and zip utility by using following command
**sudo apt-get install zip unzip**
now right click on the file which you want to extract and choose extract here.